# Sass watch will not compile - tried everything

Tags: macos, terminal, sass, rubygems, macos-high-sierra

I spent all day trying to track this down yesterday. I upgraded to High Sierra and Sass watched stopped compiling. It appears to be listening getting here:

> Change detected to: test.scss

But never compiles when I update a scss file. It used to work fine. Here are some of the things I have tried.

- Uninstall Sass / Reinstall
- Try older version of Sass
- Try older version of Listen
- Update Xcode
- Delete sass-cache
- Try to watch simple scss file

Really stumped here and need to get some changes ready - Any ideas or workarounds? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. I think I was just a little bleary-eyed. I did all of these things - learned a bit about gems along the way. Uninstalled Sass and Sass-listen, reinstalled, rebooted and back in biz.